# Why this sql can be written like this?

Tags: sql

[image]

I want to group by ssex field and then take out the records with the largest sage within each group .

```
select * from student  ,
 
  (select max(sage) maxAge,ssex from student group by ssex) as st2 

where student.ssex=st2.ssex and student.sage= st2.maxAge;
```

Question: why can a subquery be used after "from student" ?

Answer (score 1):

This works because in the relational set theory which underpins all SQL databases, tables are formally defined as a persisted form of **relation**. Query results are just another form of relation. In queries, you can **JOIN** any kind of relation (table, subquery, view, table-value constructor, whatever) to any other kind of relation.

So the code we have in the question uses the old **join** syntax that has been obsolete since 1992 to join a table relation with a query relation. It  *should* be written like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM student st1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT max(sage) maxAge, ssex 
        FROM student 
        GROUP BY ssex
    ) as st2 ON st1.ssex = st2.ssex and st1.sage = st2.maxAge;
```

Hopefully that makes more sense to you.

But also, today we would write this kind of query with a windowing function instead of a self-join anyway, which should perform better:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, dense_rank() over (partition by ssex order by sage desc) dr
    FROM Student
) s
WHERE dr = 1
```

I would expect this to run in a small fraction of the time as the original.

So while we see the original code can be written that way, there are two good reasons *it should not be written that way*.

Answer (score -1):

select can specify multiple tables, and the cartesian product will be performed between these tables

```
SELECT fieldName FROM table1，table2 … WHERE table1.field = table2.fied AND other condition
```

table2 can be a subquery.

Comment: Yes, but **DO NOT USE** the old `A,B` join syntax. It has been obsolete for 30 years now. **ALWAYS** specific the full `A JOIN B` syntax. Also, there's no cartesian product at all because of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Proposing obsolete joining syntax within an answer should never be done.